# Bootstrap: Dropdown Checkboxes Anchor Tag Without Reload of Page

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

I have something like this:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/D2RLR/5649/
```

And it works fine for checking checkboxes from a dropdown menu in bootstrap. But the problem is that this segment of code:

```
<a href="#">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <span class="lbl"> Every day</span>
</a>
```

Will cause the page to reload if someone clicks on the text in the label ('Every day').

I don't want the reload behavior. I tried to change the anchor to a span tag, but it loses the style of onhover, highlighting the entire row together. Also tried to take out the '#' from the anchor and simply make it:

```
<a href=''>
```

but the checkboxes don't seem to be responsive to clicks.

Does anyone have any good solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

To your `dropdown-menu` add the class `dropdown-with-checkbox` (or another more qualifying class name)

then add the following script:

```
$(function(){
    $('.dropdown-with-checkbox a').click(function(e) {
        // ?: Are we clicking a checkbox inside the a-tag?
        if(e.target.type === 'checkbox') {
            // Yes, but we do not want to prevent the default checkbox behaviour
            return;
        }
        // Do not reload the page when clicking the a tag
        e.preventDefault();
    }) 
});
```

#### Sidenote 1:

Adding `e.stopPropagation();` in the click handler will prevent clicks from propegating up to the 'dropdown' handler, closing the dropdown on click.

#### Sidenote 2:

You should also structure your checkboxes like this:

```
<label>
   <input type="checkbox"> Label
</label>
```

This way, clicking the lable will toggle the checkbox.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work either. With e.preventDefault(), when i check the checkbox, it checkbox remains unchecked. Yes, clicking on the label does not refresh, but I still want my checkboxes to remain checked.

Comment: @simonzhu: check out the updated version. See if that works for you.

Comment: can you please attach the link? I am not sure where I am looking at?

Answer (score -1):

You could also go with the span approach and create a css class which changes the cursor on mouse over.

```
.pointer {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

That way you keep the mouse over effect but don't have to worry about it linking somewhere or reloading the page.